# Android YoutubePlayerView video is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using PierfrancescoSoffritti YouTubePlayerView but the videos are not visible in recycler view only the sound and thumbnail is showing. Need some help.

Here is the youtubeplayer xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/video_player" app:autoPlay="false" app:videoId="S0Q4gqBUs7c" app:showFullScreenButton="true"
    app:useWebUi="true" app:enableLiveVideoUi="true" app:enableAutomaticInitialization="true" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

The Adapter Class where the youtubeplayerview is initialized

```
package aritra.code.chatters.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.YouTubePlayerListener;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

import aritra.code.chatters.MainActivity;
import aritra.code.chatters.Models.DummyPOJO;
import aritra.code.chatters.R;
import aritra.code.chatters.databinding.SampleVideoBinding;

public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<DummyPOJO> list;

    public VideoAdapter(Context context, List<DummyPOJO> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_video, parent, false);
        return new VideoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DummyPOJO data = list.get(position);

        ((MainActivity) context).addLifeCycleCallBack(holder.binding.videoPlayer);

        holder.binding.videoPlayer.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NotNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                super.onReady(youTubePlayer);
                String videoId = data.getVideoId();
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0);
                youTubePlayer.play();

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SampleVideoBinding binding;

        public VideoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = SampleVideoBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }


}
```

Everything works fine except the visibility of the video

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from adding the following inside manifest.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Once that is removed, everything works fine.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads

here is the official sample code for android you can follow as per guide